# Animation Drawable- App Stops Working After Adding A New Line to The List

Tags: android, android-animation, xml-drawable

I'm working with Animation Drawable to create a kind of a story for a simple android game. After pressing "start" button, a story appears with a skip button. Everything works fine till I add a new photo to the list of photos that represent the story line, the whole app stop working & says : "unfortunately app has stopped "

Here is my XML File :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homeone" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hometwo" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homethree" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homefour" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homefive" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homesix" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homeseven" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tableone" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tabletwo" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tablethree" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tablefour" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tablefive" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tablesix" android:duration="50" />
    //After adding the last line "tablesix", the app stop working

</animation-list>
```

And Here is my Java file:

```
package xx.tellme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class StoryLine extends Activity{

    ImageView story;
    ImageButton skip;
    AnimationDrawable anime;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stortlinelayout);


            story = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            skip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.skipbut);

            anime = new AnimationDrawable();
            story.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dlist);

            anime =(AnimationDrawable) story.getBackground();

            anime.start();

            skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent("xx.tellme.KAR"));
                }
            });


    }

}
```

What shall I do ? or is there another way to create this away Animation Drawable?

Comment: You can examine the Java stack trace to try to learn what is going wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @CommonsWare That's Help me a lot! Fatal exception main, the memory run out of space because of photo size was too big to handle. All I have done is reducing the images size.
Really Thanks, u saved me day :)